# Why doesn't Mathematica return the identity matrix for the 0-th power of a singular square matrix?

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

My understanding is that by definition, the 0-th power of any square matrix is the identity matrix. This is what [the mathworld entry for matrix powers](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MatrixPower.html) and answers to a [math.SE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/699740/zero-matrix-to-the-power-of-0) assert.

Yet when I ask Mathematica to compute the 0-th power of a singular matrix,

```
MatrixPower[{{1, 1}, {1, 1}}, 0]
```

I get the following error message and the unevaluated input back out.

```
MatrixPower::sing: Matrix {{1,1},{1,1}} is singular.
```

Obviously I can fix this by unprotecting MatrixPower and defining:

```
Unprotect[MatrixPower]
MatrixPower[m_?SquareMatrixQ, 0] := IdentityMatrix[Length[m]]
Protect[MatrixPower]
```

But I'd like to understand this properly. Is there some reason that a non-singular matrix might be thought not to have a 0-th power? Can someone explain what is going on?

Comment: Well, that depends on the definition... what would you say $0^0$ is?

Comment: Recommend that you use `MatrixPower[m_?SquareMatrixQ, 0]:= ...`

Comment: @BobHanlon Good point. Thank you, and fixed.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Consider a general $2\times 2$ matrix, and its general power $n$:

```
f[a_, b_, c_, d_, n_] := FullSimplify @ MatrixPower[{{a, b}, {c, d}}, n]

MatrixForm @ f[a, b, c, d, n]
```

[image]

The denominator is $\sqrt{4bc+(a-d)^2}$, so it looks like there's no problem with it for a matrix like `{{1,1},{1,1}}`. Let's simplify things:

```
MatrixForm @ f[1, 1, 1, 1, n]
```

[image]

There's the culprit: for `n=0` an indeterminate form $0^0$ occurs, hence the error.

There's no problem with non-singular matrices, e.g.

```
f[1, 1, 1, 0, 0]
```

> {{1,0},{0,1}}

Finally,

```
Limit[f[a, b, c, d, n], n -> 0]
```

and

```
Limit[f[1, 1, 1, 0, n], n -> 0]
```

both give

> {{1, 0}, {0, 1}}

but

```
Limit[f[1, 1, 1, 1, n], n -> 0]
```

> {{1/2, 1/2}, {1/2, 1/2}}

Comment: Thank you! This makes sense in terms of what Mathematica is trying to do, I guess. But is it correct in doing so? I thought that by definition the 0-th power of any square matrix, including a singular matrix, is the identity matrix of the same size. E.g. from mathworld: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MatrixPower.html
Or from SE: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/699740/zero-matrix-to-the-power-of-0

Comment: Oddly, `Limit[MatrixPower[{{1, 1}, {1, 1}}, n], n -> 0]` evaluates to `{{1/2, 1/2}, {1/2, 1/2}}`

Comment: @BobHanlon Makes some sense from the point of view of syntax: `Limit[0^n + 2^n, n -> 0]` seems to take $0^n=0$ and then proceed with the rest of the limit. Can the fact that `MatrixPower[{{1, 1}, {1, 1}}, 0]` does not return an identity matrix be considered a bug?

Comment: It's not a bug.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau, it may follow a spec, but it is mathematically weird… Maybe the doc for MatrixPower should be explicit about this?